# IntelliJ Idea seperates comments from import statements - difficulties to use pre-processor

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, preprocessor

I am trying to create a software which is implemented as a product line. For optional features the dependencies should, of course, be optional. But I am not able to add the needed pre-processor dorectives ( = comments) before and after a import running a code format changes this and makes this unusable...

Before code format:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
//#ifdef stackAdd
// @formatter:off
import java.util.function.Function;
// @formatter:on
//#endif
```

After code formatting IntelliJ changes this to:

```
//#ifdef stackAdd
// @formatter:off
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
// @formatter:on
//#endif
```

In the "Reformat File" dialog I have "Whole file" and "Optimize imports" enabled. This does not happen, when "Optimize imports" is disabled. I kind of still want to have things auto imported and removed if no longer needed...

Anyone has a tip what can I do this with IntelliJ?

Thank you!

PS: I know the example is a silly one, but it demonstrates what I want nicely...

Comment: Request is [welcome in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA). There doesn't seem to be a way to achieve what you need in the current IntelliJ IDEA version.

Comment: Submitted the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171179